# spring boot connect to elasticsearch docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elasticsearch docker instance.
This is the Dockerfile:

```
# https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.3

# Add your elasticsearch plugins setup here
# Example: RUN elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
```

and this is the elasticsearch.yml

```
---
## Default Elasticsearch configuration from elasticsearch-docker.
## from https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/blob/master/build/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
#
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

# minimum_master_nodes need to be explicitly set when bound on a public IP
# set to 1 to allow single node clusters
# Details: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17288
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

## Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks
## see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
#
discovery.type: single-node
```

This is the Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
      #- ./elasticsearch/config/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/:ro
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx3g -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/:/usr/share/kibana/config:ro
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:

  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

When I launch docker-compose up --build command I have this log for elasticsearch:

```
[INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [1s-uDJD] using discovery type [single-node]
[INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [1s-uDJD] starting ...
[INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [1s-uDJD] publish_address {172.18.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
[WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [1s-uDJD] initial heap size [268435456] not equal to maximum heap size [3221225472]; this can cause resize pauses and prevents mlockall from locking the entire heap
[INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [1s-uDJD] publish_address {172.18.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
[INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [1s-uDJD] started
[INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [1s-uDJD] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

what is the configuration on spring boot to connect to elasticsearch?
I don't want to connect to embedded elasticsearch.

I tried with:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=docker-cluster
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.http.enabled=true
```

Alternatively I tried with this lines in place of the first two

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.host=localhost
spring.data.elasticsearch.port=9200
```

This is an extract of spring boot console log

```
08/05/18 17:01:32.394 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.AutoConfigurationPackages - @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'it.test.elk'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
08/05/18 17:01:33.174 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.node - [Nuklo] version[2.4.6], pid[18808], build[5376dca/2017-07-18T12:17:44Z]
08/05/18 17:01:33.175 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.node - [Nuklo] initializing ...
```

If I connect with Kibana I can not find the index to which my Entity refers and I can not find any documents

Someone can help me understand how I can connect to the docker instance ?